# fs.readFile Function Response is undefined... Any Ideas?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, console

Im running a simple readfile command, for a video tutorial, and this is the code exactly as the instructor saved it...

```
var fs = require("fs");
console.log("Starting");
fs.readFile("./sample.txt", function(error, data) {
console.log("Contents: " + data);
});
console.log("Carry on executing");
```

i have the sample.txt in the same folder as this js file,
and in the sample.txt file i have "This is a sample output for this text document",
unfortunately i get a  "undefined" as the output for the data variable in the code.

If anybody has any insight as to why this is happening, it would be wonderful if someone would help....

THANKS

Comment: Add `if (error) throw error;` as the first line of the callback and see if that tells you anything.

Comment: (Or just `console.log(error)` for that matter.)

Comment: Well `ENOENT` means the file isn't there.

Comment: But.......... The file.... is there...... Right there in the directory

Comment: Well that sure does seem odd but that's what `ENOENT` means (like, `no ent`ry found in the directory).

Comment: So when you (using Cygwin presumably) do `ls 'C:\Users\Jenny Kemp\sample.txt' you see the file?

Comment: The code is fine. Try in a path with no blank spaces and double check the file name. Maybe you are dealing with a "sample.txt.txt" file, with hidden extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try checking if the file exists first:

```
var fs = require("fs");
console.log("Starting");

fs.exists("./sample.txt", function(fileok){
  if(fileok)fs.readFile("./sample.txt", function(error, data) {
    console.log("Contents: " + data);
  });
  else console.log("file not found");
});
console.log("Carry on executing");
```

If it doesn't exists, check the path, filename and extension, because your code is OK.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on where you are running this from, the root at which `./sample.txt` gets resolved may vary.

To ensure, that it resolves relative to your module, do the following:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var path = require('path');

var sampleTxt = path.join(__dirname, 'sample.txt');

console.log("Starting");
fs.readFile(sampleTxt, function(error, data) {
  if (error) return console.error(error);
  console.log("Contents: " + data);
});
console.log("Carry on executing");
```

Answer (score 1):

Even when the file exists Why Does fs.readFile() function of Node.js always returns undefined only when console.log(data) is used it shows value. Example below

```
    var content
    function myReadFile(filepath){
    fs.readFile(filepath,'utf8', function read(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    content = data
    console.log(content); // Only this part of it returns the  value 
                          // not the content variable itself 
    })
    return content;
    }
```